# How do I delete the object on the top left corner and the text at the bottom of google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

There's this thing on the top left corner of Google Chrome when I start up the home page and for some reason I don't know how to get rid of it. Furthermore, there's this series of text on the bottom that I don't know how to remove either. Can anyone help me?

[The thing at the top left of Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMC2F.png)
[The text at the bottom of Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hRi8.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably quite new because I only noticed it today as well.

Another thing is investigating the code shows the button at the top left has id "bg-daily-refresh", suggesting it's linked to the bottom list of options.
If you click on "Chrome wallpapers", it also throws a JS error (Uncaught ReferenceError: coll is not defined)

My advice would be to leave it for a few more days, it might just something they are working on and forgot to hide from the users. Deleting permanently yourself is probably not possible unless there's an option for it somewhere but I haven't found anything.

EDIT: Actually, I just found a bunch of posts related to this, including a bug report:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=865253

And some reddit links if you wanna read more, it looks like it might be related to the new feature allowing users to use Google Photos to set background images for the New Tab page!
https://www.reddit.com/r/google/comments/9024bt/what_is_this_little_toggle_icon_that_has_just/

Comment: I have it as well